# There are multiple tibbles in one codechunk. How can show them after knit in r markdown? Everytime I only get the last tibble shown

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R markdown file, I want to the result show all the tibbles:
`df_with_desc_reorder_total`,`df_with_desc_reorder_first`,`df_with_desc_reorder_second`,`df_with_desc_reorder_third`

But everytime I knit, I only got the last tibble`df_with_desc_reorder_third`.
And I can't break this to multiple chunks, cause this is in a IF statement.

many thanks.

```
  df_total <- df %>% filter(create_de_time >= third_shift_start & create_de_time <= second_shift_end) %>%
    group_by(ITEM_CODE) %>%      
    summarise(totoal_booking = sum(QUANTITY))
  #df_total
  df_with_desc_total <- df_total %>% inner_join(grouped_description_in_20, by=c("ITEM_CODE"="ITEM"))
  df_with_desc_reorder_total <- select(df_with_desc_total,c("ITEM_CODE","DES","totoal_booking"))

  df_with_desc_reorder_total %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F)
  

  df_first <- df %>% filter(create_de_time >= first_shift_start & create_de_time <= first_shift_end) %>%
    group_by(ITEM_CODE) %>%      
    summarise(totoal_booking = sum(QUANTITY))
  #df_first
  df_with_desc_first <- df_first %>% inner_join(grouped_description_in_20, by=c("ITEM_CODE"="ITEM"))
  df_with_desc_reorder_first <- select(df_with_desc_first,c("ITEM_CODE","DES","totoal_booking"))

  df_with_desc_reorder_first %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F)
  
  df_second <- df %>% filter(create_de_time >= second_shift_start & create_de_time <= second_shift_end) %>%
    group_by(ITEM_CODE) %>%      
    summarise(totoal_booking = sum(QUANTITY))
  df_with_desc_second <- df_second %>% inner_join(grouped_description_in_20, by=c("ITEM_CODE"="ITEM"))
  df_with_desc_reorder_second <- select(df_with_desc_second,c("ITEM_CODE","DES","totoal_booking"))
  
df_with_desc_reorder_second %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F)
  

  df_third <- df %>% filter(create_de_time >= third_shift_start & create_de_time <= third_shift_end) %>%
    group_by(ITEM_CODE) %>%      
    summarise(totoal_booking = sum(QUANTITY))
  df_with_desc_third <- df_third %>% inner_join(grouped_description_in_20, by=c("ITEM_CODE"="ITEM"))
  df_with_desc_reorder_third <- select(df_with_desc_third,c("ITEM_CODE","DES","totoal_booking"))

  df_with_desc_reorder_third %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F)
```

Comment: I don’t see an if statement. Can you show the code with the if?

Comment: My first thought is to do all the work in a chunk with "include = FALSE" and then add several chunks below, each printing a single data frame.

Comment: Hi Dan Slone, Yes, you're right. I added the way you suggested. It works. But I am still wandering is there a way to directly generate 4 tibbles.

Comment: Hi Kevin, The IF stetament is just used to determine the day of the week. It's queit lengthy.  so i didn't copy paste all the code.